# why is a duplicate variable declaration exception thrown while rendering a TYPO3 Flow fluid template?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-flow

How do I debug this exception?  It is in a section that displays recently viewed items which is on a page that displays an individual item.  the templates for both sections use the same variable name in the for loops eg `<f:for each="{productArticles}" as="productArticle">`  but the exception is not always thrown when recently viewed items are listed (just links to those items are shown anyway).  The exception only seems to happen when:
I am on the page displaying a gift card and then I select a different gift card from a drop down (which shows different gift card denominations) and then when the page refreshes to display the different card and then I guess the first card displayed is now one of the recently viewed items. But if I go to another page and then back to the gift card page the error may not appear.

```
    Exception while rendering
page<TYPO3.Neos:Page>/
body<TYPO3.TypoScript:Template>/
content/
main<TYPO3.Neos:PrimaryContent>/
default<TYPO3.TypoScript:Matcher>/
element<TYPO3.Neos:ContentCollection>/
itemRenderer<TYPO3.Neos:ContentCase>/
default<TYPO3.TypoScript:Matcher>/
element<TYPO3.Neos.NodeTypes:TwoColumn>/
columns<TYPO3.TypoScript:Collection>/
itemRenderer<TYPO3.Neos.NodeTypes:MultiColumnItem>/
columnContent<TYPO3.Neos:ContentCollection>/
itemRenderer<TYPO3.Neos:ContentCase>/
default<TYPO3.TypoScript:Matcher>/
element<MyCompany.Store:RecentlyViewedProduct>:
Duplicate variable declaration, "productArticle" already set! (20141105131932df2032)
```

Here is the template:

```
<f:layout name="Default" />
<f:section name="Title">
    <h3>
        <f:translate id="MyCompany.Store.Recently-Viewed">Recently Viewed</f:translate>
    </h3>
</f:section>
<f:section name="Content">
    <f:if condition="{productArticles}">
        <f:then>
            <f:for each="{productArticles}" as="productArticle">
                <f:link.action action="showProductArticle" controller="Product" arguments="{productArticle: productArticle}">{productArticle.product.name}</f:link.action><br />

            </f:for>
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
            <p>
            <f:translate id="MyCompany.Store.No-Recently-Viewed">No recently viewed product</f:translate>
            </p>
        </f:else>
    </f:if>
</f:section>
```

and the Action for the template:

```
    /**
     * Shows most recently viewed products
     *
     * @param \MyCompany\Store\Domain\Model\ProductArticle $productArticle
     * @return void
     */
    public function recentlyViewedProductsAction() {
        $recentProduct = $this->cart->getProductArticle();
        $recentProductThree = array_reverse($recentProduct);

        array_splice($recentProductThree, 3);
        if (count($recentProduct) !== 0) {
            $this->view->assign('productArticles', $recentProductThree);
        }
    }
```

The message about a duplicate var would make sense to me if the exception was always thrown as the other template uses it too, but since it is only an occasionally thrown I don't know what to make of it.

The exception log looks like this

> Uncaught exception #1224479063 in line 116 of
>   /home/thebigcat/domains/store.thebigcat.ca/public_html/releases/20131219160416/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/TYPO3_Fluid_ViewHelpers_ForViewHelper.php:
>   Duplicate variable declaration, "productArticle" already set!
>
> 115
>   TYPO3\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\TemplateVariableContainer_Original::add("productArticle",
>   TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\Doctrine\Proxies__CG__\Mycompany\Store\Domain\Model\ProductArticle)
>   114
>   TYPO3\Fluid\ViewHelpers\ForViewHelper_Original::renderStatic(array|5|,
>   Closure, TYPO3\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContext) 113 {closure}()
>   112
>   TYPO3\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractConditionViewHelper::renderThenChild()
>   111 TYPO3\Fluid\ViewHelpers\IfViewHelper_Original::render(TRUE) 110
>   call_user_func_array(array|2|, array|1|) 109
>   TYPO3\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper::callRenderMethod() 108
>   TYPO3\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper::initializeArgumentsAndRender()
>   107
>   FluidCache_Mycompany_Store_Product_action_recentlyViewedProducts_1f6458e2b69625fca8d5707e4161562d5d061770::section_4f9be057f0ea5d2ba72fd2c810e8d7b9aa98b469(TYPO3\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContext)
>   106 TYPO3\Fluid\View\AbstractTemplateView::renderSection("Content",
>   array|1|, FALSE)

and the bottom of the Security_Development.log looks like this, with many similar errors above so I doubt its related to the problem:

> 14-11-05 13:48:48  64.39.189.157  INFO      Flow
>   Access denied (0 denied, 0 granted, 1 abstained) on resource
>   "TYPO3_Neos_Backend_GeneralAccess".

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that `productArticle` which you use for `as` in `f:for` was assigned before to this template (outside `f:for`).. So for example when in your action you do:

```
$this->view->assignMultiple(array(
        'message' => 'xxx',
        'messages' => $messages,
));
```

you cannot do `<f:for each="{messages}" as="message">` because `message` is already assigned. Use something like `msg` or `loopedMessage`..

You can use `<f:debug>` outside f:for to check if your productArticle is NULL.

And about Access denied - when you add new action to your controller, you have to flush cache.

Comment: For a different template appearing the same page the productArticle variable was assigned - not actually used in the template just assigned: `$this->view->assign('productArticles', $recentProductThree);` - different action and different controller  too. Once I commented out that assign statement the exception  went away.

Comment: wait, that's the wrong code, I meant : `$this->view->assign('productArticle', $someproductArticle);` but what is weird is like I said that code is in another action in another controller, if there are namespace issues like that then there could be many of these exceptions.